# How to add a phase shift to a sin wave in the frequency domain with fft?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, phase

I want to shift a sine wave in the frequency domain

My idea is the following:

1. Fourier-Transform
2. Add a phase shift of pi in frequency domain
3. Inverse-Fourier-Transform

In code:

```py
t=np.arange(0, 6 , 0.001)
values = A*np.sin(t)
ft_values= np.fft.fft(values)
ft_values_phase=ft_values+1j*np.pi
back_again= np.fft.ifft(ft_values_phase)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t,values)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(t,back_again)
```

I expected two images, in which one wave is shifted by pi, however I got this result

(no phase shift):

[image]

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not make a phase shift.

What you did was to add a 6000-vector, say *P*, with constant value *P(i) = j* π to *V*, the FFT of *v*.

Let's write *Ṽ = V + P*.

Due to linearity of the FFT (and of IFFT), what you have called  `back_again` is

*ṽ = IFFT(Ṽ) = IFFT(V) + IFFT(P) = v + p*

where, of course,  *p = IFFT(P)* is the difference `values-back_again` — now, let's check what is *p*...

```
In [51]: P = np.pi*1j*np.ones(6000) 
    ...: p = np.fft.ifft(P) 
    ...: plt.plot(p.real*10**16, label='real(p)*10**16') 
    ...: plt.plot(p.imag, label='imag(p)') 
    ...: plt.legend();
```

[image: antitransform of P]

As you can see, you modified `values` by adding a real component of *ṽ* that is essentially numerical noise in the computation of the IFFT (hence no change in the plot, that gives you the *real* part of `back_again`) and a single **imaginary** spike, its height unsurprisingly equal to π, for *t=0*.

The transform of a constant is a spike at *ω=0*, the antitransform of a constant (in frequency domain) is a spike at *t=0*.

On the other hand, if you *multiply* each FFT term by a constant, you *also* multiply the time domain signal by the same constant (remember, FFT and IFFT are linear).

To do what you want, you have to remember that a shift in the time domain is just the (circular) convolution of the (periodic) signal with a time-shifted spike, so you have to multiply the FFT of the signal by the FFT of the shifted spike.

Because the Fourier Transform of a Dirac Distribution *δ(t-a)* is *exp(-iωa)* you have to multiply each term of the FFT of the signal by a frequency dependent term, *exp(-iωa)=cos(ωa)-i·sin(ωa)* (Note: of course each one of these multiplicative terms has unit amplitude).

---

*An Example*

Some preliminaries

```
In [61]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    ...: import numpy as np                                                                                           
In [62]: def multiple_formatter(x, pos, den=60, number=np.pi, latex=r'\pi'): 
             ... # search on SO for an implementation
In [63]: def plot(t, x): 
    ...:     fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
    ...:     ax.plot(t, x) 
    ...:     ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(multiple_formatter)) 
    ...:     ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(np.pi / 2)) 
    ...:     ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(np.pi / 4))
```

A function to compute the discrete FT of a Dirac Distribution centered in `n` for a period `N`

```
In [64]: def shift(n, N): 
    ...:     s = np.zeros(N) 
    ...:     s[n] = 1.0 
    ...:     return np.fft.fft(s)
```

Let's plot a signal and the shifted signal

```
In [65]: t = np.arange(4096)*np.pi/1024                                                                               
In [66]: v0 = np.sin(t)                                                                                               
In [67]: v1 = np.sin(t-np.pi/4)                                                                                       
In [68]: f, a = plot(t, v0)                                                                                           
In [69]: a.plot(t, v1, label='shifted by $\\pi/4$');                                                                   
In [70]: a.legend();
```

[image]

Now compute the FFT of the correct spike (note that *π/4 = (4π)/16*), the FFT of the shifted signal, the IFFT of the FFT of the s.s. and finally plot our results

```
In [71]: S = shift(4096//16-1, 4096)                                                                                  
In [72]: VS = np.fft.fft(v0)*S                                                                                        
In [73]: vs = np.fft.ifft(VS)                                                                                         
In [74]: f, ay = plot(t, v0)                                                                                          
In [75]: ay.plot(t, vs.real, label='shifted in frequency domain');                                                    
In [76]: ay.legend();
```

[image]

Comment: In this line `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(multiple_formatter))` it should be `multiple_formatter()` (parentheses added). Also `np.int` is deprecated. Btw this code is difficult to copy-paste due to the console added prompts.

Answer (score 2):

Nice, that helped!
For anyone who wants to do the same, here is it in one python file:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, legend
def shift(n, N): 
    s = np.zeros(N) 
    s[n] = 1.0 
    return np.fft.fft(s)  
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi,1000) 
v0 = np.sin(t)                                                                                               
S = shift(1000//4, 1000)  # shift by pi/4
VS = np.fft.fft(v0)*S 
vs = np.fft.ifft(VS)
plot(t, v0 , label='original' )
plot(t,vs.real,label='shifted in frequency domain')
legend()
```

[image]